# Why is PhpStorm running tests for only some tests with extra arguments (bootstrap, configuration)?

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm and for some PHPUnit tests I can right click in the file menu on the left hand side and run some tests and it works.

In the console it shows

> /usr/bin/php -dxdebug.coverage_enable=1 /srv/live/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-clover /home/me/.PhpStorm2017.3/system/coverage/live$StringTest.coverage --bootstrap /srv/live/vendor/autoload.php --configuration /srv/live/phpunit.xml tests\src\CoreBundle\Helper\StringTest /srv/live/src/tests/src/CoreBundle/Helper/StringTest.php --teamcity

However, for other tests in another bundle when I right click and run it, the command is

> /usr/bin/php /srv/live/src/tests/src/OtherBundle/Classes/Validator/StringLengthTest.php

and the test can't run. I get a class not found error, which I attribute to the command not having the extra arguments as that in the first version above. The other thing I noticed was that the 'Run test with coverage' was only available for the first test, when right clicking in the menu.

Where does this difference originate?

My `phpunit.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit cacheTokens="true"
         colors="true"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         verbose="true"
         bootstrap="/srv/live/vendor/autoload.php">
         <php>
           <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
         </php>
         <testsuites>
             <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
                <directory>/srv/live/src/tests</directory>
             </testsuite>
         </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
            <directory suffix=".php">/srv/live/src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./web/phpunitLog/codeCoverage" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="true"
             lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./web/phpunitLog/testdox.html" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

In `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Test Frameworks` it is

[image]

Do you have any ideas on why I can run one test ok but not the other - I mean why the difference in the arguments (e.g. `-dxdebug.coverage_enable=1`)?

The `php.ini` file hasn't changed.

Comment: I've had issues in the past of not having the correct run configuration selected. Say you move from one package to another and they have different run configs, maybe different bootstrap file locations. Your configs will be auto appended on top of one another automatically with the most recent config being selected as the default. e.g. I would be passing the correct configuration, except it was pointing to the configuration of a neighbor config (which had a similar structure and bootstrapping name convention so it was easy to confuse the two)

Comment: @HunterFrazier I am working in the same project and in the screenshot I am using the same config and bootstrap files. How/where would I check if I the run config is changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (not sure if it's the best).

If I click `Run -> Edit Configurations`

Then click the plus sign and add a new PHPUnit configuration, I can choose the bundle where the tests were not working.

Now phpunit runs with the extra arguments when I right click in the file menu.

The thing is, I never did this for the test that was working, so although I found a way to get the failing test to work, I am not totally clear on why I saw the difference in the first place.

Thanks [HunterFrazier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584129/why-is-phpstorm-running-tests-for-only-some-tests-with-extra-arguments-bootstra#comment84164960_48584129) for putting the wheels in motion.